Why is my PID controlled state space system always unstable?
I am unable to find a correct gain for my controller that has to make a ball and beam system stable. The goal of the ball and beam problem is to control a Voltage (V) to move the ball to a certain position (r) ont the beam. But since it's always unstable, it seems like my controller doesn't react fast enough to the oscillations it causes. If I debug my code it seems like before my A matrix can give the changes from the first loop to "r", the "qdot" value is already to big to counter via a gain. So my system always goes to infinity. A is a linearized 6x6 matrix and B is a 6x1 matrix of the form [0,0,0,0,0,1]
This is the python code:
#Code to determine the A and B matrix

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#Define constants, state space variables, and calculate_system_matrices function...

class PIDController:
    def __init__(self, Kc, Ti, Td, setpoint, A, B, C, D):

        #initializing, for example:

        self.max_output = 24
    
    def compute(self, current_value, current_time):
        error = self.setpoint - current_value[0]  
        
        delta_time = current_time - self.prev_time
        self.prev_time = current_time
        
        # Proportional term
        proportional = self.Kc * error
        self.proportional_values.append(proportional)  
        
        # Integral term
        if self.Ti != 0:
            self.integral += error * delta_time
            self.integral = np.clip(self.integral, - 
            self.max_output/self.Ti, self.max_output/self.Ti)  
        else:
            self.integral = 0.0 
        self.integral_values.append(self.integral)  # Store integral term
        
        
        # Derivative term
        if delta_time != 0:
            self.derivative = (error - self.prev_error) / delta_time
        else:
            # Handle division by zero error
            self.derivative = 0.0  
        self.derivative_values.append(self.derivative)  
    
        self.prev_error = error
        
        # PID control law with output limitation
        if self.Ti != 0 and self.Td !=0:
            pid_output = proportional + self.Kc/self.Ti * self.integral + 
                         self.Kc * self.Td * self.derivative
        elif self.Td !=0:
            pid_output = proportional + self.Kc * self.Td * self.derivative
        
        else:
            pid_output = proportional
         
        # Apply output saturation
        pid_output = np.clip(pid_output, -self.max_output, self.max_output)
       
        # State-space model simulation
        x_next = np.dot(self.A, current_value) + self.B * pid_output
        output = np.dot(self.C, current_value) + self.D * pid_output
        
        self.r_values.append(current_value[0])
        self.error_values.append(error)
    
        return output, x_next


if __name__ == "__main__":
     # Calculate system matrices A and B from the provided system dynamics
      A, B = calculate_system_matrices() 
      C = np.array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])

     # Define output matrix C and feedforward matrix D based on your 
                         requirements
     C = np.array([[1., 0., 0., 0., 0., 0.]])
     D = np.array([[0.]])

    # Setpoint is the target value
    setpoint = 0.2
    
    # Define initial state
    initial_state = np.array([[0.1], [0], [0], [0], [0], [0]])
    
    Kc = 10
    Ti = 0
    Td = 1
    
    # Initialize PID controller with tuned parameters
    pid = PIDController(Kc, Ti, Td, setpoint, A, B, C, D)
    
    # Simulation parameters
    num_steps = 100
    current_time = 0.0  # Initialize current time
    
    # Lists to store results
    outputs = []
    r_values = []
    error_values = []
    
    current_value = initial_state
    # Simulating the system
    for _ in range(num_steps):
        # Compute control signal and update state
        output, current_value = pid.compute(current_value, current_time)
        
        # Store results
        outputs.append(output)
        r_values.append(current_value[0])  # Assuming position is the first element of current_value
        error_values.append(pid.setpoint - current_value[0])  # Calculate error
        
        # Increment time
        current_time += 0.1  # Increment current_time by 1 (assuming unit time steps)
        print("current_time:",current_time)
        #print("Output:", output, "State:", current_value)

I tried adding a Ziegler-Nichols tuner, but it's unable to find a correct gain. I tried to shorten the current_time increment, but this wouldn't either. I tried putting a limit on the pid_output, but still the system goes to infinity. To make it easier to focus on the problem, I deleted the part of the code to determine the A and B code and the ziegler nichols class.

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

I agree a lot with the previous comment. Therefore I do not bother to go into your code now. But: Maybe it is the sampling time (0.1) that is already too long. To tune a PID controller, you would normally first simulate the open system (without controller feedback) and find the time constant from there. Also, maybe there is a sign shift in the controller feedback loop.

I tried trimming down to code to only the necessary parts. I tested a variety of smaller sampling times, so I suspect the problem lies somewhere else. Another possiblity is that my methode doesnt work, but I cant see why that would be the case.
